# Bloated JS output with Webpack and Vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm getting started with Vue's [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). I created a simple *Hello World* which I bundle with **Webpack** (I'm also new to it) but I am really astonished by the bloated resulting file.

This is my component at `src/js/components/app.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello World!',
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and my `src/js/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/app.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App }
});
```

And this is my `webpack.config.babel.js`:

```
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
}
```

I use Vue 2.3.4 and Webpack 3.0.0. My resulting `main.js` file (which works fine) is >10.000 lines of code!

1. Is this normal?
2. Am I doing something wrong?
3. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Remember it will also be bundling `Vue` itself, which unminified is 9685 lines of code.

It will also be doing a bunch of other magic to convert your `ES2015` code to `ES5` and creating a [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) from your `.vue` template.

Comment: Touché! Fair enough :) Thanks!